# Access and save location information when app run in background - iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, gps, location

So my question is whether an app, which is running in the background, can access the device's location information and save it in the heap or send data to a server?
I know it would have to do something with the delegate but I'm not sure a process of this complexity can be done while the app is in the background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can!

In the Location Awareness Guide of apple its is described that application that need to receive GPS in the background have to set a specif value:

Set key `location` in the `UIBackgroundModes` array of your `Info.plist` file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can do it.

By setting the proper key-value in info.plist file, your application will able to fetch locations even when its in background.

Using ASIHttpRequest ([Link](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)), you can upload the data using web service.
For that, create the object of `ASIHTTPRequest` and keep the value of  `shouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground` to TRUE.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but what do you mean by "setting the proper key-value"?